# windows 10 firewall: block any ip address but one

Tags: windows, firewall, whitelist, netsh

i have just enabled remote desktop on a windows 10 computer, and in fact when i telnet to 3389 port from any other computer i can reach that service, but what i want is to deny the connection from any computer but a specific one (192.168.0.12), so i have issued the commands below:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_bloquea_entrada_IN"    dir=in action=block  protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=any description="Deniega RDP IN"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_bloquea_entrada_OUT"   dir=out action=block protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=any description="Deniega RDP OUT"

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_permite_guacamole_IN"  dir=in action=allow  protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.12 description="Permite RDP guacamole IN"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_permite_guacamole_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.12 description="Permite RDP guacamole OUT"
```

but all connections gets blocked, even if i swap the rules:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_permite_guacamole_IN"  dir=in action=allow  protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.12 description="Permite RDP guacamole IN"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_permite_guacamole_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.12 description="Permite RDP guacamole OUT"

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_bloquea_entrada_IN"    dir=in action=block  protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=any description="Deniega RDP IN"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP_regla_bloquea_entrada_OUT"   dir=out action=block protocol=tcp localport=3389 remoteip=any description="Deniega RDP OUT"
```

thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you adding a deny rule? That's what firewalls do, deny by default. You should only need the allow rule.

Comment: because, as i said, firewall is open for 3389 as soon as i enable rdp service, i mean, anyone is able to connect

Comment: Uncheck the "Network Level Authentication (NLA)" Option in RDP settings.

Comment: still the same bjoster, no change; it seems the rule with ip 192.168.0.12 has no effect, only the 'remoteip=any' applies; i thought that netsh would behave similarly to iptables

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the default behavior for Inbound connections is,
If it is "allow", it will only need one rule :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="my-3389" dir=in action=block protocol=TCP  localport=3389 remoteip=1.1.1.1-192.168.0.11,192.168.0.13-255.255.255.255
```

If it is "block", it will only need one rule :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="my-3389" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP  localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.0.12
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8914dab-54b6-41da-a31d-b0fddb8a2d73/block-all-access-except-certain-ip-addresses-from-stations-a-and-b?forum=winservercore

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the firewall is currently set to allow.

Answer (score 0):

Use **New-NetFirewallRule** with allow action and remoteaddress switch.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps

Comment: thankyou ishraj, but i think i will have the same issues because i think that new-netfirewallrule is the powershell's version of netsh (begin netsh the 'command version'); anyway, i will check it

Answer (score 0):

in the end, the solution i have adopted (because it worked for me!) is the one given in:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34709/enable-rdp-for-internal-network-only

"
In order to restrict RDP to specific IP addresses,

- Go to the control panel->Administrative Tools
- Windows Firewall with Advanced Settings
- Inbound Rules
- Remote Desktop (TCP-In)
- Go to the Properties->Scope tab
- Add the IP (or IP range) in the Remote IP addresses section
  "

I would have preferred a command line solution (ie, with netsh), but it was not possible